# Purify revealed a potential free memory read when using std::list::remove()

Tags: c++, stl, purify

Purify revealed a potential free memory read when using std::list::remove(). I noticed that `std::list::remove()` uses the type's `operator==` to do the comparison. However, what I have also noticed is that if the first element in the list is passed to `std::list::remove()`, it is deleted when it matches, but then it is still used to compare against all the other items in the list. This causes Purify to flag this as a "potential free memory read". I replaced the `std::list::remove()` call with `erase()` and an iterator, which is more efficient because it makes it loop only once versus twice in my situation.

Is there a reason `std::list::remove()` keeps the first element around?

Comment: what compiler and/or STL implementation?

Comment: @jsantander: gcc 4.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [GCC bug# 17012](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17012), fixed in 4.3.0. See also [Library Working Group Defect Report 526](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#526).